# NetLogo - plot sum of all turtles with value in certain range

Tags: netlogo

I would like to plot the sum of all turtles holding values in a range from 2 to 4. How can I achieve that?

I only get the sum of turtles holding a value of 4 with `plot count turtles with [value = 4]`, however, I would need something like `plot count turtles with [2 <= value => 4]`.

How can I achieve this?

My MWE is:

```
breed [ turtles ]
turtles-own [ value ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 100
  [
    set value random 4
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    rt random 360
    fd 1
  ]
  tick
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetLogo doesn't support the `2 <= value => 4` syntax. You need to write both conditions separately:

```
plot count turtles with [ value >= 2 and value <= 4 ]
```

By the way, if you wanted to plot the *sum* of the values instead of the *count* of turtles with values in that interval, you could write:

```
plot sum [ value ] of turtles with [ value >= 2 and value <= 4 ]
```

Comment: Thank you, Nicolas. This has helped me.